# Update markers Google Maps API with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am having trouble with the code to update markers in Google Map API. I have `$.ajax` function that downloads data. Then I initialize the map `initMap()` and I iterate through data received from `$.ajax`. I create markers, push them into an array `Markers`. The markers successfully display on the map.  Then I need to update markers every 5 seconds. So I defined a new function `setInterval` that will run a function `updateMarkers` The function `updateMarkers` removes markers from the map and sets an array of markers to an empty array. Then I call again $.ajax function(i get error 'undefined - I guess because of the scope). Then I run function `Markers(Data)`. I tried to refactor the code multiple times. I get as far as removing and deleting markers from an array. Then I get infinite loop that downloads data and pushes them into array and my browser freezes. Could anybody help me out with the code below? I would really appreciate it!

```
var map;
var marker;
var markers = []; 
var locations = [];


$(function downloadJSON() {
    type: 'GET',
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url....',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: Markers
    });
});

function Markers(data) {

    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        var position = data[i].location;
        var title = data[i].title;
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: position,
            title: title,
            id: i
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        }
}

function initMap() {
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(10,-10),
                  zoom: 15
                }); 

setInterval(function() { 
       updateMarkers();
    }, 5000);

function updateMarkers() {

    downloadJSON();

    //remove markers from the map and delete array markers:
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     markers[i].setMap(null);
     markers = [];
    }

Markers(data);

}

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&v=3&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you updating the markers ever 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't call updateMarkers() using every 5 seconds. Call it when the user interacts with the map. Google maps library offers a very useful event listener for this:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', updateMarkers);
```

Secondly, I don't see the reason for the updateMarkers function to exist. Just add something to the Markers function to clear the map and the array before adding the new ones.

```
function Markers(data) {
    // clear map
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    // clear array
    markers = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        var position = data[i].location;
        var title = data[i].title;
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: map,
           position: position,
           title: title,
           id: i
       });
       markers.push(marker);
    }
}
```